# Как правильно закрыть ссылку на рубрику от индексации в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал рубрику 'original' (чтобы помечать индивидуальные статьи) в wordpress, которую хочу сделать скрытой для поиска и визуального отображения (для улучшения seo)
1- Для начала исключил ее из вывода в списке категорий на странице согласно [ЧАВО](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

```
query_posts($query_string .'&cat=-1'); if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

2 - Следующим этапом закрываю в индексации в файле **robots.txt**
`Disallow: /category/original/`

3 - И последнее нужно добавить ссылкам категорий атрибут **rel=”nofollow”**, чтобы они не передавали вес
нашел способ сделать это в файле **functions.php** для всех рубрик - вот так:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_rel_nofollow_to_wp_list_categories');
function add_rel_nofollow_to_wp_list_categories($a) {
return str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ', $a);
}
```

А как сделать индивидуально под мою - правильно делаю?

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_rel_nofollow_to_wp_list_categories');
function add_rel_nofollow_to_wp_list_categories('original') {
return str_replace('<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ', 'original');
}
```

Comment: а чем не подходит запретить роботам посещать каталог с помощью файла robots.txt?

Comment: @Vladimir Novopashin подходит, но вес ссылки рубрики все равно передается, а он ведет вникуда..

Answer (score 1):

> которую хочу сделать скрытой для поиска и визуального отображения

Можно сделать [кастомным типом записи](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) без включения в архивы и тд.
Можно сделать [шаблон поста](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types) (аналогичный шаблону страницы) или [шаблон темы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).
Можно подключать нужный хедер (get_header) по условию рубрики (in_category).

Comment: спасибо, но а можно все же по моему методу - обратиться к конкретной рубрике и добавить к ней атрибут `rel=”nofollow”` ?

Comment: Если речь об атрибутах ссылок, то я не знаю. Да  и вообще подобные сео-фантазии, как  перетекание и размазывание веса ссылок (отчасти и сам их вес). мне малоинтересы, если честно. Я предпочитаю заморачиваться более полезными и продуктивными вещами.

Comment: понял, и на том спасибо!